# Making a picture identical to another one

Tags: applications, camera, images

**Let me start with a goal:**

There is an old picture of a person taken in a specific location.

I would like **to take the same picture preserving the same view and the same position of the person on that picture**.

My assumption is that it would be easier to do that when I can see the previous picture during the process of making a new one. Going further, it would be even better if the previous picture would be visible in the camera app itself in the background, so I can compare prev picture with the one I'm going to take in a runtime!

Is there any mobile camera app allowing to set a semi-transparent background picture to help to make such a picture?

Are there any other workarounds to archive this goal?

Comment: Something like [Now and Then](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.geneanet.vuesHier)? I vaguely remember another app (having something with "history" in its name) but cannot find it anymore.